# How Can i View Column Name Values on DataGridView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img835/2255/75787362.jpg](http://a.imageshack.us/img835/2255/75787362.jpg)

CourseID, ProfessorId and StudentID are foreign keys, i want
to print CourseName, ProfessorName, StudentName instead of ID's.

I'm using the wizard (typed dataset).

Note: the three id's are of composite pk as well fk, so no duplicate
records will appear.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make another table where each id = his name. from there
you can invoke all the matching names. Not sure if this is what you are looking for but I hope it helps.